# Frames vs User controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, frames

I'm writing a Windows application in WPF. I based my UI in a single menu and a tab control to display different documents or application forms. Since the menu as well as other things are fixed throughout the application, I need a way to display the contents of each *TabItem*. I have found two:

1. write  a user control for each form, or
2. using  a frame to display the content of each form.

#### The question

Is there any other single way for doing this. How do they compare in terms of clean code?  I mean, in .net forms I only need load the form from the menu.

I know, I should go for any pattern like MVVM, but for this very first time I want to use  the default approach.

Comment: I go with Frames and host Pages (not user controls).  I like Pages over User Controls as the event model seems to have more hooks.   I too plan to go to MVVM some day but for a small project it is a bit of overkill.

Comment: @Blam: Put your comment into an answer so Manuel can accept it. Apparently it helped him.

Answer (score 0):

I go with Frames and host Pages (not user controls). I like Pages over User Controls as the event model seems to have more hooks.